# Clicking text-description for checkbox only toggles the first checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a panel with some check-boxes. Check boxes are being filled by jquery call to some C# code.

I realized that when clicking on the text of the name that represents the check-boxes (being done by a data-bind for a span tag) that the checkbox did not toggle on and off. I implemented a name and id for my input tag, and now only the first checkbox toggles when clicking the text. The other boxes/texts do not repeat this functionality.

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="scroll" style="height:260px;" tabindex="0" data-bind="foreach: Services">
                <div class="col-xs-6" id="ReviewerServices">
                    <div class="checkbox" >

                        <label for="serviceCheckbox">
                            <input type="checkbox"  name="serviceCheckbox" id="serviceCheckbox" data-bind="checked: IsSelected" />
                            <span data-bind="text: ServiceAliasDescription"></span>
                        </label>

                    </div><!-- end checkbox -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- col-xs-4 -->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So two things about what you've done... the first is that `id` **must** be unique on the page.  the second is that assuming you understood that `for` binds the label to an input with the matching `id`, why didn't you expect that clicking on any label would check/uncheck *all* of the boxes :-)

Basically, what is happening is that you have multiple `serviceCheckox`s and telling every label to affect "the thing that is called serviceCheckbox" and as soon as the browser finds the *first* "serviceCheckbox" it checks or unchecks it.

What you *should* do is index the `id` and the `for` accordingly.  I've never used knockout, so my syntax might be wrong, but hopefully you get the idea

```
<label data-bind="{for: 'serviceCheckbox' + $index}">
  <input .... data-bind="{id: 'serviceCheckbox' + $index, checked: IsSelected}" />
  <span ..... >
</label>
```

Comment: You are correct about what is going on, I was able to remove the for="serviceCheckbox" in my label and this solved the issue.

Comment: Actually, with duplicate ids your code isn't valid html... but I guess that is neither here nor there.  :-)  Don't forget to accept my answer!